# Determine if all values are adjacent integers in R

Tags: r, integer

I'm trying to test if all values in an object (if ordered) are adjacent integer values.  For example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
is.adjacent(x)
TRUE

y <- c(1,2,4)
is.adjacent(y)
FALSE

z <- c(4,2,1,3)
is.adjacent(z)
TRUE
```

Any thoughts on a good approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution. I've constructed it so that it will return `TRUE` for a vector that contains a set of consecutive integers, even it some of them are repeated (e.g. `c(1,3,2,1,1,1)`). If you would like it to return `FALSE` in such cases, just remove the part that calls `unique()`.

```
is.adjacent <- function(X) {
    all(diff(sort(unique(X))) == 1)
}

# Try it out
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,4)
z <- c(4,2,1,3)

is.adjacent(x)
is.adjacent(y)
is.adjacent(z)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you'd also want the function to test whether `X` is an integer vector, (so that something like `c(3.5, 4.5, 2.5)` does not evaluate to `TRUE`) but that seems too pedantic to have added to the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already had a (separate) function which first tested if the elements were integers.